# Would it be okay to learn Ruby On Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, programming-languages

I know HTML&Css, Little Javascript & Little PHP.
I really want to get in the world of programming languages and I think Ruby looks way better then PHP. But I might be wrong.

Should I stick learning PHP?
Or should I go along with Ruby On Rails?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304972/learning-a-new-web-oriented-programming-language-where-to-begin

Comment: I personally would give Python a shot before RoR

Comment: The question is rather subjective; it's all depends on what you plan to do, as PHP and ruby are two different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should learn the technologies in the [LAMP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29).

If you are into web development, its important to build up a good foundation with HTML+CSS+JS. Personally, I believe that PHP is a good starting point, given the vast resources/help there are on PHP. In the long run, I think that learning PHP will pay off. Most people who know Ruby have prior experience in PHP. Its OK to learn Ruby once you have a good understanding of LAMP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty much a subjective question.  RoR is popular for getting things done quickly.  That doesn't mean that you can't also be efficient with PHP.  There have been some scaling issues with RoR, but I'm not sure if that issue is inherent to RoR or simply due to its relative youth.  There are some oddities inherent to PHP for historical reasons.  (E.g. variations in function naming conventions, function argument order and some weirdness in OOP, to name a few.)

Ultimately, you'll want to try them both in order to decide for yourself.  Being relatively new to programming, you may want to pick one and stick with it for a while.  However, there's no reason that you can't use either one, as appropriate for your needs.  As kingjeffrey states, they are both just tools.  As I like to think of it, programming is a state of mind, the languages are just syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends upon what you plan on building. If you will be building vanity websites and blogs, stick with PHP (and a CMS or two, like WordPress). If you will be building more involved web apps, learn Ruby (and the Ruby on Rails framework).

I've done (and do) substantial work in both. At the end of the day, they are just tools. To know what tool is right for the job, evaluate the job.

Comment: Could Ruby ON Rails be used for Mobile Apps too?

Comment: @kawohi If you mean a web app to be used by a mobile device, sure.  Either PHP or RoR could be employed for that.

Comment: Ruby and PHP are server side technologies. They output HTML that can be accessed from any web browser (whether mobile or not). However if you want an app in the Android or iPhone App Stores, web technologies will not help you. You will need to learn their APIs and the languages their APIs require.